# Arrows not displayed on Chrome

Tags: html, sharepoint-2013, html-table, web-parts

I am using the Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise platform and in an empty zone I have inserted some custom HTML:

```
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" valign="top" class="s4-wpcell-plain ">
   <table class="s4-wpTopTable " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="ms-WPBorderBorderOnly" valign="top">
               <div webpartid="47e70058-3c1d-4f9f-902c-d8a25861a63f" haspers="false" id="WebPartWPQ2" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex " allowdelete="false" style="">
                  <div class="egovstyle-FontSize-4" style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration: none;">​​</span></span><span style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration: none;"><strong>EVEN​​TS​​ / NEWS</strong></span></span></span></div>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/2016%20Competitions%20for%20Local%20Councils%20and%20NGOs.aspx">Competitions for Local Councils and NGOs</a></p>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/Programme%20of%20Activities%20for%202016%20in%20Malta.aspx">Programme of Activities EMW 2016</a></p>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/Press-Conference-EMW-2016.aspx">Press&nbsp;Conference&nbsp;European&nbsp;Mobility&nbsp;Week&nbsp;2016&nbsp;</a></p>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/Government-Grants.aspx">2016 Scrappage Scheme and Grants​</a></p>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/Electromobility-Day-at-MCAST.aspx">Electromobility Day at MCAST​</a></p>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/Greening-the-Environment-Initiative-Awarded.aspx">Port-PVEV receives award​</a></p>
                  <p><span class="egovstyle-Style-arrow"></span><a href="/en/Pages/Deployment%20of%20Green%20Infrastructure.aspx">Transport Malta deploys 13 Electric Vehicles​</a></p>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
```

On other browsers (IE/Firefox) it appears properly:

[image: In Firefox/IE]

But on Chrome it is shown as below:

[image: In Chrome]

Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, try adding the span-element before the a-element for the two items just like you did for the other ones?

Comment: Please post your css